# searching for a part of the url (without protocol)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my database i store urls as string, with protocol validation, meaning there has to be a "http://", "https://" or "ftp://" before hostname. 
Also, to my controller action POST request is being sent, but just with hostname, no protocol. How can I search database for this hostname? 
The easiest solution would be to just construct new string with protocol, but i dont know which one i'm going to need. It might be "https" just as well as "http".
Any ideas?
(NOTE: This is Rails 3 app)

EDIT

It's been pointed out that my question is not clear, so I will try to explain it better now.
In database i have column url. It stores links which begin with "http://", "https://" or "ftp://".
they may look like this:
url:

```
"http://google.com"
"https://amazon.com"
"ftp://somehostname.com"
```

My controller gets POST request with hostname, it may be  `{"domain" => "google.com"}`

So now what i need to do is search the database for "google.com" to update it. BUT as you can see, value under "domain" key doesnt store protocol. So i dont know if it is `"http://google.com"` or `"https://google.com"`, yet i must somehow find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.host
request.host_with_port
request.url
```

[request.host](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionDispatch/Http/URL/host)

The just query with .where(:url => current_url)

Not exactly sure what you're asking but these should point you in the right direction (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are going to get a URL without the protocol in one of your POST params and you want to match it with the ones in your database which HAVE a protocol.

This is what I would do:

Option 1:
If feasible store the protocol and rest of the URL in two separate fields in the database. Easy to compare that way.

Option 2:
Use regular expressions!
Let's say you get params as follows:

```
{"domain" => "google.com"}
```

I would then do this to find the record:
(Assuming name of your model is "Record")

```
domain = params[:domain]    
@record = Record.where('name = ? OR name = ? OR name = ?', "https://#{domain}", "http://#{domain}", "ftp://#{domain}" )
```